# Building NetworkManager from source causes ProtectSystem capaibilities to stop functioning

Tags: network-manager, compiling, systemd

I'm fairly new to `systemd` in general, and building a program that fully supports the `ProtectSystem` capability is a bit over my head.

I'm trying to understand which options I should supply to `./configure` given the restrictions of `ProtectSystem=true`.

In this case, I pulled down `1.15.91` and built it straight away with:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

NetworkManager's execution is handled properly with systemd init but the child `dhclient` can't properly access a file path as it's in `/usr/local`, which I've learned is not in conformance with the `ProtectSystem=true` directive.

In the case of the NetworkManager build, autogen was used and the usual environment parameters are present:

```
--prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in [/usr/local]
--exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX [PREFIX]
--bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
--sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
--libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
--sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
--sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
--localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
--libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
--includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
--oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
--datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
--datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
--infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
--localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
--mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
--docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/NetworkManager]
--htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
--dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
--pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
--psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]
```

Which options should I supply to mimic the locations of the standard NetworkManager build included with the distro?